# React-Router with Reactstrap results in warning

Tags: react-router, reactstrap

I have a navbar with a brand, and I want the brand to be a link to the main page.

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

.
.
.

<Navbar color="white" light expand="sm" className="py-0">
  <NavLink to="/">
    <NavbarBrand>
      <img src={ logo } />
    </NavbarBrand>   
  </NavLink >
</Navbar>
```

This results in this a warning:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.
    in a (created by NavbarBrand)
    in NavbarBrand (at NavBar.js:53)
    in a (created by Link)
    in Link (created by Route)
    in Route (created by NavLink)
```

How do I keep using reactstrap with react-router then?

Answer (score 1):

Both `<NavbarLink />` and `<NavbarBrand />` render an HTML anchor (`<a>`).

By passing one as a child of the other one, you are rendering an anchor inside another one, which is not HTML valid, and this is why your browser warns you.

Easiest solution would be to use the `tag` property to choose your own component to render, and use a function to define specific props such as `to="..."` :

```
<Navbar color="white" light expand="sm" className="py-0">
  <NavbarBrand tag={(props) => <NavLink to="/" {...props} />}>
    <img src={ logo } />
  </NavbarBrand >
</Navbar>
```

PS : pay attention not to mix up reactstrap `<NavLink />` and react-router `<NavLink />` :)
Use renamed imports if you need to.